# Who is in charge of the Back Lands?

Tags: the-lion-king, the-lion-guard

In the animated TV series, *The Lion Guard*, (a sequel spin-off to *The Lion King*) there seems to be four separate regions such as the Pride Lands, Out Lands, Back Lands, and Snow Mountain.

I don't understand who has authority in the Back Lands, because of an incident with leopards not obeying Dhahabu, a Golden Zebra who seems to be Queen of the Back Lands. Does King Simba have any authority over her or the Back Lands?

Answer (score 2):

Although I have seen a few episodes, I haven't seen them all or have payed very close attention, but doing some research from [The Lion King Fandom Wiki](https://lionking.fandom.com/wiki/Back_Lands), it appears that Simba does NOT have authority there.

The episode titled, *"The Trouble with Galagos"* is about how one Leapoard from the Back Lands is bullied by another Leopard and pushed out of their territory and Kion and his Lion Guard companions found the Leopard on their land (The Pride Lands) and decides to return the Leopard home.

But in another episode, *"The Golden Zebra"*, when they are finally taken to Queen Dhahabu, they learn that there is situation with the Back Land's drinking hole running dry, and make a deal that they will help her with her problem, if they can drink from the hole. She agrees and they fix the rock slide problem. In a later episode still, Dhahabu travels to the Pride Lands to discuss "the water treaty" with King Simba, as Kion continues to play mediator.

**So no, Simba has little authority in these other lands who are ruled by other animals**. However there are "relationships" established and **negotiated** between leaders of these territories (say for the Outlands), so that resources can benefit the many in need of them.

> After training with the Lion Guard, Badili returns to the Back Lands
>   and forces Mapigano to leave Mirihi Forest. The front works, and
>   Mapigano leaves to stake out territory elsewhere. The Lion Guard
>   praises Badili for his courage, and Badili thanks them for helping him
>   fight for his turf.

As for the Leopard dilemma, they seem to be given their own territory within the Back Lands to live on and standing up for one's self seems to be a condition of their species to be able to stay on the land. there is no additional information to explain why Dhahabu does not intervene.

And really the whole notion of 'The Lion Guard' itself, purposes that there is a group **needed in the Pride Lands to go around and uphold values of The Circle of Life**, that means that other animals often cause "problems" that the Lion Guard has to "fix". It's not necessarily a matter of "disobeying" a leader, although there are more obvious ill-intended villains, as much as it's not necessarily easy keeping "balance" in check. Most likley this situation exists for other "territories" or regions and isn't exclusive to The Pride Lands, which gives the characters common ground to work with.

Comment: Oh I think I understand but these other lands are considered regions? Also why is queen zebra doesn’t have laws for leopards she has less power on her back lands as simba could easily take over of he wants too?

Comment: Yes, these places are described as territories separate to the Pride Lands. Again, as I explained, there is no in-universe explanation for why Zebra Queen was ok with the Leopard's philosophy, only that we might presume that is just the way Leopard's believe to exist (on this land), and that like Kion, they all just accept it.

Comment: what u mean, @darklocke Shouldnt they obey her similar like how animals obey Simba

Comment: As I explained in my answer, not all of the Pride Land animals obey Simba and/or they end up having problems, that is why there is a Lion Guard, to help maintain order. If everything would be perfect, then there wouldn't be a need for The Lion Guard.

Comment: what u mean no aniamls respect the king they seem to be. during season 2 but im asking about back lands the leopards dont obey golden zebra. i dont see why simba wants to ask for permission to use their watering hole if he wants can take it if he wanted too. what u meant by Friendly leoaprd he not native to pride land. He from back lands that was kick out by another leopard

Comment: to bad i cant chat with here maybe i can understand better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104649/discussion-between-darth-locke-and-john-pass).